# Is [iterator] applicable to C++ std-style iterators?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I recently encountered a [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) question about providing standard-library-style iterators for a particular class. I did some copyediting on the question, and seeing as we have an [iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iterator) tag, thought I'd add that too.

However, the excerpt (and entire wiki) for that tag only mentions "iterator" as the GoF design pattern of that name. The Iterator design pattern is different from C++ std-style iterators in that the GoF Iterator comes with an `IsDone` (or equivalently `HasNext`) query, which C++ iterators most often cannot provide.

In light of this, I did not add the tag, but I thought I'd ask here for guidance. A tag usable for std-style iterators would be useful. What would the correct course of action be?

1. Extend the tag wiki for [iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iterator) to note that GoF Iterator is not the only way of doing iterators,

or

2. Establish a new tag for C++ std-style iterators?

I would personall go with option 1 (seeing at the concepts are still very similar and an expert in one will likely have equally valid insight in the other), but I would love to hear both [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) community feedback on this.

Comment: I haven't seen that much iterator only related c++ questions. wouldn't we need to make different tags for several mayor c++ "features" then? I'm not really against or for it. But it may clutter the tags a lot if you start with too many language specific features (not only c++)

Comment: I personally vote for option 1.  It makes it a lot easier for new people looking for tags if the correct tag to use is *iterator* and not *c++-iterator* or some other variation of that.